# Update command update all the data in table

Tags: mysql, asp.net, vb.net, updates

Currently my program working fine for adding and update data , but when  update the data it update all the data that from same StaffID.Even the Staff id adding new data and update the new data the old data from the same id will update all the old one.  here is my code:

```
Using sqlConn2 As New MySqlConnection(strConnectionString)
            sqlConn2.Open()
            Using sqlComm2 As New MySqlCommand()

                sqlComm2.Connection = sqlConn2
                With sqlComm2


                    .CommandText = "update cr_record " & _
    "set cr_record.isu=@isu," & _
    "cr_record.Nama=@Nama," & _
    "cr_record.pnum=@pnum," & _
    "cr_record.date1=@date1," & _
    "cr_record.DeptDesc=@DeptDesc," & _
    "cr_record.email=@email," & _
    "cr_record.change1=@change1," & _
    "cr_record.reasonchange=@reasonchange," & _
    "cr_record.problem=@problem," & _
    "cr_record.priority=@priority," & _
    "cr_record.reasondescription=@reasondescription," & _
    "cr_record.systemrequest=@systemrequest " & _
    "where cr_record.Emplid=@Emplid and cr_number"
                    .CommandType = CommandType.Text
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@cr_id", cr_id)
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@Emplid", txt1.Text)
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@isu", ddl1.SelectedItem)
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@Nama", TextBox1.Text)
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@pnum", txt3.Text)
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@date1", txtDate.Text)
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@DeptDesc", txtdep.Text)
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", TextBox3.Text)
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@change1", ddl2.SelectedItem)
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@reasonchange", txt6.Text)
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@problem", ddl3.SelectedItem)
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@priority", rbl1.SelectedItem)
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@reasondescription", txt7.Text)
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@systemrequest", ddl4.SelectedItem)

                    '' .Parameters.AddWithValue("@attachment", FileUpload5)
                    ''  .Parameters.AddWithValue("@jobDesc", TextBox4.Text)
                    '' .Parameters.AddWithValue("@locDesc", TextBox5.Text)
                End With
                Try

                    sqlComm2.ExecuteNonQuery()
                    MsgBox("Data has been modified successfully!", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Updated!")
                Catch ex As MySqlException
                    MsgBox(ex.Message.ToString())
                End Try
            End Using
        End Using
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have not given value for the second attribute "cr_number" after "where" clause

```
.CommandText = "update cr_record " & _
"set cr_record.isu=@isu," & _
"cr_record.Nama=@Nama," & _
"cr_record.pnum=@pnum," & _
"cr_record.date1=@date1," & _
"cr_record.DeptDesc=@DeptDesc," & _
"cr_record.email=@email," & _
"cr_record.change1=@change1," & _
"cr_record.reasonchange=@reasonchange," & _
"cr_record.problem=@problem," & _
"cr_record.priority=@priority," & _
"cr_record.reasondescription=@reasondescription," & _
"cr_record.systemrequest=@systemrequest " & _
"where cr_record.Emplid=@Emplid and cr_number=@cr_number"
```

Comment: you have to add the parameter for @cr_number

Comment: all the parameter i just include it.. but still have fatal error execution

Comment: if it helped you, you can upvote flag it as right answer

Comment: where will you get the cr_number. i mean textbox or any?

Comment: the cr_number is not from text box is the primarykey AI n.NULL and id for that table. but i just declear dim cr_number as integer